# Loop Without Do Error

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, do-while

I am trying to loop through three lists of data and hide the rows that have a total value of 0. Although I keep getting A "Loop Without Do" error, can someone spot what I have done wrong.

Cheers.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Brow1 As Integer
Dim Brow2 As Integer
Dim Brow3 As Integer

Dim Trow1 As Integer
Dim Trow2 As Integer
Dim Trow3 As Integer

Brow1 = 62
Trow1 = 3
Brow2 = 126
Trow2 = 67
Brow3 = 190
Trow3 = 131

Do While Brow1 > Trow1

    If Range("P" & Brow1).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Brow1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ElseIf Range("P" & Brow1).Value <> 0 Then

       Brow1 = Brow1 - 1
Loop


Do While Brow2 > Trow2

    If Range("P" & Brow2).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Brow2).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ElseIf Range("P" & Brow2).Value <> 0 Then
       Brow2 = Brow2 - 1
Loop

Do While Brow3 > Trow3

    If Range("P" & Brow3).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Brow3).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ElseIf Range("P" & Brow3).Value <> 0 Then
       Brow3 = Brow3 - 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

None of your If statements are closed appropriately.  Add an "End If" after each "ElseIF" and you should get your expected behavior:

```
Do While Brow1 > Trow1

    If Range("P" & Brow1).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Brow1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ElseIf Range("P" & Brow1).Value <> 0 Then

       Brow1 = Brow1 - 1
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `End If` part of every `If` statement.

You can also get rid of the `Else If` test and just use `Else`:

```
Do While Brow1 > Trow1
    If Range("P" & Brow1).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(Brow1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
       Brow1 = Brow1 - 1
    End If
Loop
```

You have another problem though. The first time you find `Value = 0` you end up in an infinite loop because the value of `Brow1` never gets reduced. A better version would be a `For ... Next` loop:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = Brow1 To Trow1 Step -1
    If Range("P" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```